# How can a join of an array of delimiter separated template types be represented in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a string that is a delimiter-separated join of an array of various template types. Is there a way that I can represent this as a typescript type? Something like this:

```
type Foo = `foo:${string}`;
type Bar = `bar:${string}`;

type Fragments = Foo | Bar;

// Is something like this possible?
type JoinOfFragments = Array<Fragments>.join(';');

const example1: JoinOfFragments = 'bar:456';
const example2: JoinOfFragments = 'foo:123;bar:456';
const example3: JoinOfFragments = 'bar:789;foo:123;bar:456';
const example4: JoinOfFragments = '';
```

Comment: It is [possible](https://tsplay.dev/NDkqOw). But you really don't want to do this. The order of elements in a union is not something you can rely on. It could change without a warning between TypeScript versions or otherwise behave strangely. This solution is a "hack" which you should not use.

Comment: You should rather think about an alternative solution: Maybe you define `Fragments` as a tuple and then derive a union from that with `Fragments[number]`.

Comment: @TobiasS. I will take a look at your example, but I should clarify I did not mean to imply that I meant for order of the elements in the union to be significant, rather that that union represented the possibilities for each element of the join which could be of any length. I added some other examples to clarify

Comment: This would only be possible in combination with a generic function: https://tsplay.dev/N7OxPN . A stand alone type will not validate repeating sequences

Comment: I'm confused by your example; any string that begins with `"bar:"` or `"foo:"` will match `Fragments` itself.  That is, `"foo:123;bar:456;foo:789"` matches `Fragments` because it starts with `"foo:"`.  And `"foo:123;blap:999*dk2Kfd43)*"` also matches.  There are no extra things to be added by allowing two or more `Fragments` to be concatenated; only the empty string `""` is added.  Therefore the type you want is just `Fragments | ""`.  If you're looking for something else, you should [edit] the example to clarify.